# How to prevent the same letter in a row in regex

Tags: regex

I am supposed to write a regex that contains only U and W alternately or only W and U or an empty set. I am only allowed to use `?`, `*`, `+`, `|` and `()`. If I write `(WU)*|(UW)*`, the it doesn't match the single U and W and UW neither. But if I add a U or W to it, then it already matches too much. I'm sure the solution is simple, but I just can't figure it out.

So allowed is:

- U
- W
- UWU
- WUWU

not valid:

- UU
- WW
- WWUUU
- UUW

Comment: Something like `^(U?(WU)*W?|U|W|)$`?

Comment: Thank you, this is working, but I am afraid, that I am not allowed to use ^$.  :(

Comment: It is not possible without the beginning- and end-of-string anchors `'^'` and `'$'`. If, for example, you have a regex that matches, say, `'UWUW'`, it will also match, for example, `'UUWUWWW'`. I suggest you make that point and provide a regex that includes the two anchors. @Wiktor, you can simplify to `^U?(WU)*W?$`.

Comment: why are you not allowed to use ^ and $ ? What are you using ? maybe you can use something else to match the begening and end like a space or linebreak

Comment: Because it is an exercise from the school and we are only allowed to use the very basics (?+*|)

Comment: What would your teacher say when he finds out you solicit homework answers online ?

Answer (score 2):

```
W?(UW)*U?|U?(WU)*W?
```

This matches either `W` followed by a series of `UW` optionally followed by `U`, or `U` followed by a series of `WU` optionally followed by `W`. Making the first character optional allows for an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but that does not work, because it matches for example WWUUU also.

Comment: It needs to be anchored so it matches the whole string, but you're not allowed to use `^` and `$`. I don't know how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^U?(WU)*W?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i6FooN/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5EU%3F(WU)*W%3F%24):

[image]

Note that without *[anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)* you can't make sure your regex matches full string if you need to put all requirements into the pattern. It is also possible to use specific regex matching functions in various languages, to name a few:

- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) - `std::regex_match`
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `re.fullmatch`
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) - `String.matches` / `Pattern.matches`
- [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) - `kotlin.text.matches` or  `Regex.matchEntire`
- [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) - with `==~` operator
- [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) - same as in [java](/questions/tagged/java) or with `match` block if the regex is not declared as `.unanchored`

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `U?` - an optional `U`
- `(WU)*` - zero or more sequences of `WU`
- `W?` - an optional `W` char
- `$` - end of string.

Note: in Ruby (Ongimo regex library), you need `\A` and `\z` anchors, i.e.

```
\AU?(WU)*W?\z
```